# hadoop - tasks keep running after job finished

Tags: hadoop

I running an hadoop cluster with 20 nodes.

I run a heavy job which uses a lot of memory.
for some reason it seems that some tasks get "out of touch" with the job.
why does it seem so?

1. I have a task timeout of 600 seconds. and these task run much more than that. I know so by looking at the java processes.
2. after the job is completed I still have map reduce processes running.

have anyone encounter such problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. the task will only be killed if there is no progress report on it for 600 seconds. As long as there is some progress the task will continue.
2. that should not be happening. Are you sure that the processes are from your job? If you restart the same jobs a few times you still might have a few hanging processes if you have not properly stopped an older job.